# Elasticsearch - re-index data-stream in order to remove some unwanted fields

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

In according to this documentation [data-streams-use-reindex-to-change-mappings-settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/data-streams-change-mappings-and-settings.html#data-streams-use-reindex-to-change-mappings-settings), I have crated my new data-stream with the associate index-template which have my new fields mapping, but when the reindex start to perform, it add all the unwanted fields that I have previously removed from the new mapping settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake =) you need to set "mapping.dynamic"="false" in your index template.